# Validation rule sometimes shows the customised error messages and sometimes a more detailed error

Tags: validation, validation-rule

The same validation rules we have on this object are sometimes showing the messages nicely as we worded
them:

[image]

And other times it shows this more detailed message (which we'd prefer it wouldn't show to applicants):

[image]

Comment: These fields are shown in a Candidate Portal to which users connect via a site and a guest user (so everybody accesses the portal with the same guest user). Some people get the long error and some people get the nicely worded error.

Comment: Is this a custom page where you're displaying this error message? If so, any code you could provide would be helpful.